# Case Statement with Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary, switch-statement

Hi all i wrote the following code, what i am doing is i would like to use `Switch` case for my `dictionary` that exists but i am getting an error as

`Can not implicitly convert string to bool`

My code is as follows

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Delete");
lst.Add("Reports");
lst.Add("Customer");

Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1, "Delete");
d.Add(2, "Reports");

    foreach (string i in lst)
    {
        if (d.ContainsValue(i))
        {
            switch (d.ContainsValue(i))
            {
                case "Delete": // Here i would like to compare my value from dictionary
                    //link1.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx";
                    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Delete.aspx";
                    break;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            HyperLink2.Attributes["OnClick"] = "alert('Not a Valid User to Perform this operation'); return false";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d.ContainsValue(i)
```

returns boolean. When you do this:

```
case "Delete"
```

You try to compare the bool with a string, so it fails. You need to do this:

```
if (d.ContainsValue(i))
{
    switch (i)
    {
        case "Delete": // Here i would like to compare my value from dictionary
            //link1.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx";
            HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Delete.aspx";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've identified the problem, but how about a solution?

Comment: I am getting the following errors `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,string>.this[int]' has some invalid arguments` and `cannot convert from 'string' to 'int' `

Comment: I updated the answer, there was an error there. You **already** have the value in `i`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:     `switch (d[i])`

It would probably be more efficient to use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

the `if` inside the `switch` return a boolean value while the `case` says it must be a `string`

```
 switch (d.ContainsValue(i))
            {
                case "Delete": // Here i would like to compare my value from dictionary
                    //link1.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx";
                    HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Delete.aspx";
                    break;
            }
```

try this

```
switch (d[i])
                {
                    case "Delete": // Here i would like to compare my value from dictionary
                        //link1.NavigateUrl = "Reports.aspx";
                        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Delete.aspx";
                        break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and avoid the switch all together:

```
var lst = new List<string>();
lst.Add("Delete");
lst.Add("Reports");
lst.Add("Customer");

Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>();
d.Add(1, "Delete");
d.Add(2, "Reports");

var hyperlinkMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Delete", "Delete.aspx"},
    { "Reports", "Reports.aspx"}
};

foreach (var i in lst)
{
    if(d.ContainsValue(i))
    {
        HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = hyperlinkMap[i];
    }
    else
    {
        HyperLink2.Attributes["OnClick"] = "alert('Not a Valid User to Perform this operation'); return false";
    }
}
```